# Why the following python code outputs blank contour plot?

Tags: python

I'm getting the blank plot by using the below code and data file. Could you please let me know what's wrong with data file or the code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                  
data = np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', delimiter=' ')                                                                                                                                                             
lats =  data[:,0]                                                                                                                                                                      
lons =  data[:,1]                                                                                                                                                                     values = data[:,2]                                                                                                                                                                      
lat_uniq, lat_idx = np.unique(lats, return_inverse=True)
lon_uniq, lon_idx = np.unique(lons, return_inverse=True)                                                                                                                           
xre, yre = np.meshgrid(lon_uniq, lat_uniq)
zre = np.full(xre.shape, np.nan)                                                                                                                                            
zre[lat_idx, lon_idx] = values
print(zre)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (10, 5))
cp1 = ax1.contourf(xre, yre, zre, levels=4)
plt.colorbar(cp1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("data are not interpolated")                                                                                                                                   plt.show()
```

test.txt file --

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

10 11 12

[image]

Comment: Please enter your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has no problem
There were none values in your matrix, in which case the graph will not be drawn.

It makes no sense to have null values in a matrix and try to draw those points.

By changing its values, the 'contourf' command can fit the values of X, Y, and Z, and the graph is drawn.

See this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', delimiter=' ')
lats = data[:, 0]
lons = data[:, 1]
values = data[:, 2]
lat_uniq, lat_idx = np.unique(lats, return_inverse=True)
lon_uniq, lon_idx = np.unique(lons, return_inverse=True)
xre, yre = np.meshgrid(lon_uniq, lat_uniq)
# zre = np.full(xre.shape, np.nan)
zre = np.full(xre.shape, 0)
zre[lat_idx, lon_idx] = values
print(zre)

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
cp1 = ax1.contourf(xre, yre, zre, levels=4)
plt.colorbar(cp1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("data are not interpolated")

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've a question regarding this code-posted the new question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712652/why-i-am-getting-different-plots-for-the-same-data-file-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712652/why-i-am-getting-different-plots-for-the-same-data-file-in-python