# Why I am getting different plots for the same data file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

txt file

```
1 1 1
1 2 2
2 4 9
4 5 2
6 1 1
6 2 8
6 4 9
6 5 2
2 5 3
4 2 5
4 3 8
4 4 5 
1 3 4
1 5 2
2 1 1
2 3 4
```

I got Fig 1 using the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                  
data = np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', delimiter=' ')                                                                                                                                                             
lats =  data[:,0]                                                                                                                                                                      
lons =  data[:,1]                                                                                                                                                                     values = data[:,2]                                                                                                                                                                      
lat_uniq, lat_idx = np.unique(lats, return_inverse=True)
lon_uniq, lon_idx = np.unique(lons, return_inverse=True)                                                                                                                           
xre, yre = np.meshgrid(lon_uniq, lat_uniq)
zre = np.full(xre.shape, np.nan)                                                                                                                                            
zre[lat_idx, lon_idx] = values
print(zre)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (10, 5))
cp1 = ax1.contourf(xre, yre, zre, levels=4)
plt.colorbar(cp1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("data are not interpolated")                                                                                                                                   plt.show()
```

and I got fig2 by using the below code and same data file

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', delimiter=' ')
lats = data[:, 0]
lons = data[:, 1]
values = data[:, 2]
lat_uniq, lat_idx = np.unique(lats, return_inverse=True)
lon_uniq, lon_idx = np.unique(lons, return_inverse=True)
xre, yre = np.meshgrid(lon_uniq, lat_uniq)
# zre = np.full(xre.shape, np.nan)
zre = np.full(xre.shape, 0)
zre[lat_idx, lon_idx] = values
print(zre)

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
cp1 = ax1.contourf(xre, yre, zre, levels=4)
plt.colorbar(cp1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("data are not interpolated")

plt.show()
```

Which of the code and contour plot is correct? The first, second and third column in txt file represents x, y and z values, and I want to create a contour plot using above data file. Thanks.

Comment: @Saeed EmamYari

Comment: Because the second code assumes, for whatever reason, that nonexisting data are zero. I don't know why the other user assumes this - you have to ask him.

Comment: Also note that for non-grid data, `plt.tricontourf(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2])`  would create triangles from the actual points instead of an arbitrary grid.